# Redirecting from one CGI page to another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, perl, cgi

I am a nembie to CGI with Perl, please do help me out and please do correct me wherever I have committed a mistake.

This is the code. The problem is that after the password is validated and found as correct, instead of redirecting to the next page it is giving this message:

```
Status: 302 Found
Location: http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi
```

---

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
use strict;
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $q = new CGI;
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

if ($q->param("Login")) {
    my $Password = param('Password');
    if (!$Password) {
        print "Please Enter the Password";
    } else {
        my $dbh = DBI->connect(
            "dbi:SQLite:DEVICE.db",
            "", "",
            {
                RaiseError => 1,
                AutoCommit => 1
            }
        );
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from Settings where Password = ?");
        $sth->execute($Password);
        if (my $pass = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
            print redirect(-url => 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi');

        } else {
            print "Invalid Password";
            display_form();
        }
        $dbh->disconnect;
    }
}

if (($q->param("submit"))) {
    process_form();
} else {
    display_form();
}

sub process_form {
    if (validate_form()) {
    }
}

sub validate_form {
    my $User_Password = $q->param("Password");
    my $error_message = "";
    $error_message .= "Please enter the Password<br/>" if (!$User_Password);
    if ($error_message) {
        display_form($error_message, $User_Password);
        return 0;
    }

}

sub display_form {
    my $error_message = shift;

    print <<END_HTML;
<html>
    <head><title>Form Validation</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <TABLE align="center" bgcolor=#B0C4DE>
                <TR>
                    <TD> Enter The Password And Click Login</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD><b>PASSWORD</b> : <input type="password" name="Password" size="20" maxlength="15" /></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD align="center" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
                        <input type="reset" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
END_HTML
}
```