# How can I redirect the client from one CGI page to another using Perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

My problem is the following. After the password is recognized as valid I need to redirect to `main.cgi` but I am getting the message as:

```
Status: 302 Found
Location: http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi
```

I know the reason for this is that I am writing this statement after `Content-Type` so it is taking this as HTML and printing it on screen. I am a newbie to Perl. Can anybody please help me find the solution for this and make my code work the way I want it to? Or please suggest me some alternative code for this, or any link which might help me out.

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
my $q = new CGI;

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

if ($q->param("Login")) {
    my $Password = param('Password');
    if (!$Password) {
        print "Please Enter the Password";
    } else {
        my $dbh = DBI->connect(
            "dbi:SQLite:DEVICE.db",
            "", "",
            {
                RaiseError => 1,
                AutoCommit => 1
            }
        );
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from Settings where Password = ?");
        $sth->execute($Password);
        if (my $pass = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
            print redirect(-url => 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi');
        } else {
            print "Invalid Password";
        }
        $dbh->disconnect;
    }
}

print <<END1;
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE> </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <form NAME="login"  METHOD="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <TABLE align="center" bgcolor=#B0C4DE>
                <TR>
                    <TD> Enter The Password And Click Login</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD><b>PASSWORD</b> :<input type="password" name="Password" size="20" maxlength="15" /></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD align="center" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
                        <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Cancel">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
END1
```

Comment: Haven't really looked at this, as you said, you're new and this has many well-formedness issues, but print the content-type later down, if you know that's the case.

Comment: HEY THANKS ALOT... i had put it jst above the print<<END1...it works perfectly navigating to the intendented page..bt if i enter the wrong password then instead of dispalying "invalid password"..the page is getting refreshed thas al..i tried puttin it jst abve the statement print "invalid password";,,bt its giving an ERROR : INTERNAL SERVER ERROR,,,,,,wen i checked the error logs then ths s wat i found out.."malformed header from script. Bad header=<HTML>: Login.cgi",..THIS IS A NEW ISSUE NOW...please do help me out solve it,,if it gets solved then every problem in my program is sorted out...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting from one CGI page to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649762/redirecting-from-one-cgi-page-to-another)

Answer (score 21):

The redirect:

```
print redirect(-url=>'http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi');
```

only works when it's the first thing sent back to the browser.  Because you're sending this first:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
```

the redirect is being treated as content.

(The redirect has to be the first thing you send because it belongs in the HTTP headers of the response.  By printing your `\n\n`, you're explicitly terminating those headers.  After that, anything you send is content and will be displayed by the browser.)

Answer (score 6):

you might want to try

```
print "<META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh CONTENT=\"1;URL=http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi\">\n";
```

the trick is `CONTENT=\"1` will delay page redirect for about one second

I had the same problem so this trick worked for me pretty good.
The code is not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 2):

See the following, hopefully it will give you a good idea about how to keep control flow "to the right" and will help you identify exactly which pieces do what and should do what, in your form:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Windows does not use #! to launch stuff!
use strict;
use warnings; # always!
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;

my $q = CGI->new;

my_program:
{
    if ( !$q->param('Login') or !length $q->param('Login') ) {
        print $q->header('text/html'), my_form(); # just display the form
        last my_program;
    }

    my $password = $q->param('Password');
    if ( !$password or !length $password ) {
        print $q->header('text/plain'), "Please enter the Password";
        last my_program;
    }

    my $dbh = DBI->connect(
        "dbi:SQLite:DEVICE.db",
        "", "",
        {
            RaiseError => 1,
            AutoCommit => 1
        }
    );
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from Settings where Password = ?");
    $sth->execute($password);
    if (my $pass = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
        print redirect(-url => 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi');
        last my_program;
    }
    print $q->header('text/plain'), "Invalid Password";
}

sub print_my_form {
return <<END1;
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE> </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <form NAME="login"  METHOD="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <TABLE align="center" bgcolor=#B0C4DE>
                <TR>
                    <TD> Enter The Password And Click Login</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD><b>PASSWORD</b> :<input type="password" name="Password" size="20" maxlength="15" /></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD align="center" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
                        <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Cancel">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
END1
}
```

Never mind you never use the "Login" parameter... the above performs the redirection as you want it, displays the errors with no form (use a `print my_form()` after the header line if you need to), and looks generally a bit tidier.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Mr.mfontani..i pasted this code..whenever i give a valid password then its getting redirected to the Main.cgi..But whenevr i give wrong password then a dialog box appears asking "YOu want to save or open the file Login.cgi"..and when i click Open then its DIsplaying the MEsSage "invalid password" in PERL EXPRESS...actually am using PERL EXPRESS to execute my perl programs..

Comment: You need to use $q->header('text/plain') above in the occasions where you're just giving out the errors, and $q->header('text/html') when presenting the form; updated

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a page to another use the following method.

```
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Session::Plugin::Redirect;
my $session = new CGI::Session();
print $session->redirect('http://example.com/redirect-path/redirect-file.php');
```

Search [***`www.search.cpan.org`***](http://www.search.cpan.org) for more details about the session module.

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way is to use the META refresh tag, you wont need to regig your header either.

Use this code:

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
my $q = new CGI;

my $redirect = 0;

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

if ($q->param("Login")) {
    my $Password = param('Password');
    if (!$Password) {
        print "Please Enter the Password";
    } else {
        my $dbh = DBI->connect(
            "dbi:SQLite:DEVICE.db",
            "", "",
            {
                RaiseError => 1,
                AutoCommit => 1
            }
        );
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from Settings where Password = ?");
        $sth->execute($Password);
        if (my $pass = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
            $redirect = 1;
        } else {
            print "Invalid Password";
        }
        $dbh->disconnect;
    }
}

print <<END1;
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
END1

if ($redirect){
    print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/cgi-bin/Main.cgi/">';
}

print <<END2;
        <TITLE> </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <form NAME="login"  METHOD="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <TABLE align="center" bgcolor=#B0C4DE>
                <TR>
                    <TD> Enter The Password And Click Login</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD><b>PASSWORD</b> :<input type="password" name="Password" size="20" maxlength="15" /></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR></TR>
                <TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD align="center" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
                        <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Cancel">
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
END2
```

Comment: A Million thanks Mr.Darren..it works exactly the way i wanted it to work..after a valid password it shows the form again for a while and later gets it redirected to main.cgi...BUT APART FROM THAT EVRY BIT WORKS PROPERLY....tahnks a lot....

Comment: Meta Refresh is what you use when you can't do it correctly, as in the highest voted answer in this question.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but it was pretty obvious Sonya was looking for a simple solution with as little re-writing as possible.